# Cannot access FTP directory with CP1250/CP852/UTF-8 encoding

Tags: encoding, ftp, python-3.6

I am trying to read in some files from the following directory structure:

```
/jc/06 Önéletrajzok/Profession/Előszűrés sablonok név szerint
```

But for some strange reason I cannot enter not even in the upper level directories.

I already tried with PHP/Python3.6/Ruby but without much luck. At least with PHP and Python I can CWD() at least until the `/jc/06 Önéletrajzok/Profession` part.

Here is my python code for reference:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('hostname')
ftp.login('username','pwd')
ftp.cwd('jc') # Just for demonstration purposes as step by step
ftp.cwd('06 Önéletrajzok')
ftp.cwd('Profession')
print(ftp.nlst()[2]) # Which gives: 'ElÅ\x91szÅ±rÃ©s sablonok nÃ©v szerint

# But when I am trying:
ftp.cwd('ElÅ\x91szÅ±rÃ©s sablonok nÃ©v szerint')
# Or either:
ftp.cwd('Előszűrés sablonok név szerint')
# It gives: 
# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0151' in position 6: ordinal not in range(256)

# So I am trying encoding CP1250 or CP852 (for Hungarian)
dir = 'Előszűrés sablonok név szerint'.encode('cp852') # which gives: b'El\x8bsz\xfbr\x82s sablonok n\x82v szerint'
ftp.cwd(dir.decode('utf-8'))
# and it gives the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 2: invalid start byte
```

So I am starting to give up on this one, I don't know how to access those files. The directory structure was created with Windows laptops accessing a Synology File server.

I have already tried with `ftp.encoding = "utf-8"` too.

Any ideas?